# Дефис при образовании исковерканных слов наподобие "что-то-там": что это за правило?

Tags: орфография, дефис, словоизменение, окказионализмы, языковые-изменения

Скажите, как правильно оформить "переделанную" часть слова, если, например, персонаж не запомнил его и произносит в исковерканном виде, "приклеивая" части от себя? Пример: слово "астролябия"; производное от него вида "астр-что-то-там" как пишется, через дефисы? Какое существует правило на этот счёт (не нашёл такого), и встречаются ли подобные примеры в литературе?

*— Астролябия лежала тут, а теперь её нет! Ну а глобус где?*

*— Глобус разбился, а эта, **астр-что-то-там**... Не видел я её, вот...*

**ДОПОЛНЕНО (02.11.2022)**

"Грамота.ру" наконец ответила и считает, что дефисы оправданны (см. [здесь](http://new.gramota.ru/spravka/buro/search-answer?s=310056)):

> Специального правила на этот счет нет, но полагаем, что предложенное Вами написание оправданно. Это пересекается с регламентируемыми полным академическим справочником «Правила русской орфографии и пунктуации» случаями употребления дефиса в выразительных целях. В том числе —  для выделения (смыслового и произносительного) какой-либо части слова; для передачи произношения по слогам с разными целями (произнесение говорящим незнакомого слова, смысловое выделение важного слова и др.).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Это направление словообразования иногда называют "окказиональные дефисные комплексы". Мне удалось найти пример написания подобного выражения в работе [«Типология окказиональных дефисных комплексов в романе В.
Аксенова "Редкие земли"»](https://kpfu.ru/staff_files/F599250432/2_Spiridonov_AV_tez.pdf).

> тридцати-с-чем-то-летней давности

Что касается правила, то в справочниках такое мне не попалось. И думаю, не попадётся. Окказионализмы порой выходят за рамки грамматически правильных выражений, зафиксированных в учебниках о том, как "надо писать". Думаю, это тот самый случай.

Также добавлю, что вот [тут](http://www.gramota.ru/class/coach/tbgramota/45_122) "Грамота" рассматривает похожий, хотя другой вопрос, который тоже может оказаться вам интересен (когда частицы -ТО, -ДЕ, -ТАКИ находятся внутри сложного слова, части которого соединены дефисом).